# zeppelin additionalRemoteRepository URL config in Dependency Management for Interpreter Spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-zeppelin

I am stuck adding the following class to zeppelin:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.10/7.5.2

What is the syntax for zeppelin.dep.additionalRemoteRepository to add mvnrepository.com here?

I also deployed a local version of apache archive, and tried https://archiva.secscs.com/repository/internal (where archiva.secscs.com is my local DNS name), but none worked.

Can you please give a hint what is the URL value I can put in the additionalRemoteRepository URL?

Thanks,
--Larry

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [official documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/usage/interpreter/dependency_management.html). For your example:

- Go to interpreters page and click edit on the Spark interpreter
- At the bottom there is *artifact* field, fill it with: `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.10:7.5.2` (always on the form of `groupId:artifactId:version`)
- Save the modifications and Zeppelin will restart the interpreter to load the added dependency.

Antoher way is using `%spark.dep` interpreter to load dependencies :

```
%spark.dep
// add maven repository
z.addRepo("RepoName").url("RepoURL")

// add artifact recursively
z.load("groupId:artifactId:version")
```

See [Dynamic Dependency Loading via `%spark.dep` interpreter](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#3-dynamic-dependency-loading-via-sparkdep-interpreter) for more details.